# TypeScript code completion// dependent variable does not show up

Tags: javascript, typescript, code-completion

I want to create a code completion via TypeScript. I have the command:

```
Variable.Append1
Variable.Append2
Variable.Append3
```

Now I have created this class:

```
class Variable{
    Append1(name: string){
        if (name == undefined){
           return 0;
        }
        return name;
    }
    Append2(name: string){
        return name;
    }
    Append3(name: string, defaultValue: string){
        if(name == undefined){
           return defaultValue;
        }
        return name;
    }
}
```

I have added it to my library and my JavaScript file recognize the 'Variable' parameter but not the Append1, Append2 and Append 3. I am a very beginner to TypeScript and would be happy for every help!

Comment: Code Completion is part of the IDE and not the library itself.

Comment: Those are instance methods, not static methods.

Comment: Yes and in my IDE I have intergrated my .ts file. Therefore it should recognize these parameters and complete them or am I wrong?

Comment: They should be instance methods or they should be static methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Append1`, `Append2`, etc are instance methods of `Variable` class. You can access them if you create an instance of `Variable`:

This would work:

```
let variable = new Variable();
variable.Append1("test"); // works
```

If you intended `Append1`, `Append2`, etc to be static methods mark them as such:

```
class Variable {
    static Append1(name: string){
        if (name == undefined){
           return 0;
        }
        return name;
    }
    // ...
}

Variable.Append1("test"); // works
```